# Current state remain in listview android.

Tags: android

I have a activity which showing the 20 items in listview, at bottom list view has a footerview as "**Load more results** when we clicked the load more it should add next 20 results on it, this is working fine.

But after clicking on load more the whole page get refreshed and it is showing from the top.
while it should show items from current position. Is there any method????
The data is coming from the parsing.

Thanx

Comment: I think you are using new adapter when loading of 20 more items. Avoid it and simply add 20 row data to previous adapter, don't create new one.

Comment: thanx pankaj. I got the solution there is listview method setSelection(int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a global counter in where your `ListView` knows where your counter (or *index*) is. Simply increment the counter when adding a new item from the parsing data. When the `ListView` dynamically downloads more items, you should put in your counter into the parsing process so you just download new data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the solution there is a method setSelection(int position).

Comment: @Himanshu: Well, I think I misunderstood your question, but you have already solved it anyways. :-)